# Problem with ATI Radeon HD 7670M on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati, fglrx, overheating, inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity does not start after installing the fglrx drivers on 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210040/unity-does-not-start-after-installing-the-fglrx-drivers-on-12-10)

I updated from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 a couple of days back.

My machine is a [Dell Inspiron 15R](http://www.dell.com/in/p/inspiron-15r-5520/pd) with a **Radeon HD 7670M** Graphic Driver.

When I was using 12.04, I was able to install the propriety driver using the notification you usually get. But after the upgrade, the graphic driver is not getting installed.

- I am not getting the notification to install the driver
- And I also tried to follow the steps given - [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

  - I tried the legacy as well as the usual installation procedure
  - Both ways I failed and my graphics went to the fallback, disabling Unity

Note: My laptop is getting heated to 80 degrees and can shut down at any point. Please help.

Comment: You can try the detailed steps mentioned here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/202857/cant-install-ati-proprietary-drivers-in-12-10/207270#207270

Comment: This is a bug and should be closed as one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/+bug/1069199

Comment: @Aniket - since this is a confirmed bug and also a duplicate - I'll refund this bounty and close the question.  Thanks.