# 12.10 starts up to just my desktop background

Tags: drivers, display, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity does not start after installing the fglrx drivers on 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210040/unity-does-not-start-after-installing-the-fglrx-drivers-on-12-10)

I have only just started using linux more than just instlling it on an old pc for fun and have just changed the driver settings from the default option. The computer starts up and goes through everything else well, but at slightly lower resolution. Once signing on to Ubuntu, it only displays my desktop background and cursor.

Can i restore it to the default driver settings? I've spent a while transferring files and don't want to reinstall Ubuntu.