# 'X Error of failed request: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)' after installing the AMD binary driver on 12.10

Tags: drivers, 12.10, ati, graphics

I have just installed the binary driver for AMD hardware on Ubuntu 12.10 using the "Installing upstream drivers directly from AMD's website" method. But now when I run 'fglrxinfo', I get this message:

X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
Serial number of failed request:  12
Current serial number in output stream:  12

How can I get the driver working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no AMD driver available that installs and is able to run Unity successfully. For more information and follow up on the bug please check out this post

- [Unity does not start after installing the fglrx drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210040/unity-does-not-start-after-installing-the-fglrx-drivers-on-12-10)

Remove the proprietary driver and use the open-source one for now.

Comment: Does it help that I use GNOME panel and not Unity?

Comment: It has to do with the X version 12.10 uses, have not tested but would assume there would still be issues.

Comment: Okay, is there any other driver option? The default is giving me a very low performance.

Comment: You can always downgrade to 12.04 and use any driver you want.

Comment: No options for 12.10?

Comment: Still not from what I can test.

Answer (score 1):

The AMD Beta drivers released on 2012-12-03 work for 12.10, as long as you're running single monitor.

I had this issue and was able to get fglrx to report the video card version properly and my system booted into gnome3 proper with cloned monitors. Trying to enable multi-monitor, though, caused the system (on the next reboot) to fall back into gnome classic with multiplying gnome bars across the main monitor. Moving the mouse toward the second monitor caused it to loop around to the opposite side of the first monitor, very pacman-like.

@Harris6310, you might try the current beta drivers to see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Are the current beta drivers 'fglrx-updates'?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, @Harris6310. The current beta drivers are downloaded via AMD. [wiki.cchtml.com](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide) is a good place to start.