# When will fglrx be fully supported by Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, fglrx

The title pretty much speaks for itself. I want to know when I will be able to install fglrx from the Ubuntu repositories and for it to work correctly? It seems to work fine on 12.04 but not 12.10 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess you are having the same problem I have. You can follow the [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1025488) to see how the progress is.

Until it's fixed you can use the fglrx legacy driver. It's unofficial but it works fine for me. It added some fixed to the driver so it will work with the 3.5 kernel. Sadly it downgrades the XServer from 1.13 to 1.12.4.

If you want to try it, there is a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx) for it. You can install it from the terminal with.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am okay with the default driver. I just wanted to know when the fix will come about. I'll follow that launchpad link.

Answer (score -1):

The AMD Beta drivers released on 2012-12-03 may help for 12.10, as long as you're running single monitor.

[Read this for more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/226707/113385)

Comment: Are the beta drivers what fglrxinfo-updates are? Because if so, I still get the same problem.