# No menues orlauncher after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dist-upgrade

I have a system having run plain Ubuntu for 4-5 years. All updates have been installed at availability and worked nice. After upgrade to 12.10, I am without menus and launchers. No window borders and no possibilities for resizing or moving windows. Launching 'ccsm' I see an error saying something like: Can't write - dconf channel is closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely it is something in the config that was done on a previous release that is now causing problems for Unity.  Prior to 12.10 you could just 'unity --reset' however this no longer works.  Have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration), particular the second one which is for 12.10

Comment: There are indeed some oddities in my installation with different kernel versions reported in different places - from 3.0.0-12 to 3.5.0.19. I may eventually end up making a install

Answer (score 0):

The kernel in a new installation comes ready to upgrade with a .17 kernel and headers for the .18 version.

You basically need to install linux-headers-generic before installing the graphics driver.

You can see my own solution [here on ask-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210040/unity-does-not-start-after-installing-the-fglrx-drivers-on-12-10) towards the bottom of the page although admittedly some steps maybe be unnecessary i.e. excessively cautious. However, that's what got it working for me, which is the main thing.

Comment: This is in right direction. I have an nvidia-card (GT 9400). I found in the startx log (in the terminal after "startx -- :1"): "Fatal error: nvidia-current not found". There is no file close to that name in Synaptic.

Comment: No experience with Nvidia I'm afraid but I don't need Synaptic for the ATI driver (although fglrx is indeed there). I used the ATI driver from the software center sources.