# How to remove proprietary AMD drivers & repair Unity

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, steam

I have installed these AMD drivers for my HD 5770:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

When I launched Steam it threw me an error that something was wrong with OpenGL, told me that performance may suffer and let me proceed.
After that I attempted to download CSS, but because it was slow and didn't exit I force killed the "steam" process.
After I reboot the PC I get the login screen, which I can log in from but when logged-in I get no Unity, no Dashboard etc etc. Only my desktop background, the mouse pointer. I suspect the problem may be with the drivers displayed above, how could I remove those drivers?

EDIT: When I boot to guest mode (I can't bring up the terminal on normal account because of different layout) and launch CCSM it tells me when  I enable the Unity plugin that it needs to also enable OpenGL(asks me that twice) and some other plugins.

EDIT 2: Whenever I try sudo apt-get purge fglrx I get told that the package does not exist.

[Unity does not start after installing the fglrx drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210040/unity-does-not-start-after-installing-the-fglrx-drivers)

I've tried the answers here but none of these help.

Comment: If you're being told the package doesn't exist, it means you've already removed it and can ignore that bit. The second step of my answer should, then, bring back Unity for you (fingers crossed!)

Comment: With the second command I catch an error about not being able to spawn a command line.
("dbus launch autolaunch--[long string] binary-syntax --close-stdr": Child process exited with code 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem (unrelated to steam, but the fglrx drivers after upgrading to 13.04)

The solution, for me, was as follows:

Login, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up a terminal.

`sudo apt-get purge fglrx`

Then reboot. Login again after the restart, and put the following into a terminal window:

`gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins`

It took a while to actually run for me (maybe about 5 or 10 minutes, can't remember for sure) but eventually unity came back.

Hope this is of some help.

EDIT: Just noticed your bit about problems with the terminal. If the terminal window doesn't come up for whatever reason, try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>to open console mode - log into your account to run the command there. Hopefully that'll work as a fallback.

Comment: When I attempted to run sudo apt-get purge fglrx I get told that the package does not exist.

When I attempt to run the second command(in ctrl+alt+f1) I catch an error about not being able to spawn a command line.

Comment: Strange. I didn't get any such error when I did it. Have you also tried `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` ?

Comment: I edited some keyboard settings and managed to get the terminal up on my admin account, from which I ran the second command which fixed it.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Brilliant, glad to hear that it worked! Out of interest, was it 13.04 that had the problem for you too?

Comment: I had used 13.04 for some days, not sure what broke them for me.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the problem is simply the combination of the fglrx drivers and 13.04 in general. Each time I've tried to install them (three times, including the drivers left over from the previous version when upgrading to 13.04), Unity has simply failed to load after rebooting.