# Is it possible to bring terminal (invoked from GUI) to the CLI terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome, upgrade, ati

Due to graphics driver failure after dist-upgrading my "AMD powered" system I am unable to login to my account. The login screen is just bouncing back and not showing me the result of that upgrade process that was going on. This happens with me a lot of times, I am fed up now. I'd usually re-install my system to resolve this problem.
I have read somewhere that this problem is arising due to lack of support for AMD GPU by Gnome.

So my question is, is it possible to bring that terminal window that was invoked in the GUI to the CLI (after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)?

**Additional Details:**

```
System Configuration: AMD A8-4500M with (AMD 7640G & AMD 7670M)
Ubuntu version: 14.04 (Trusty) with GNOME
```

Also, I was not using proprietary driver as it was a fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Virtual Console**

ctrl + alt + f1

Is a virtual console, accessed when the Ubuntu OS is loaded. (ctrl + alt + f7 to return to GUI Ubuntu)

**Recovery Mode - Terminal**

Have you tried recovery mode? When the boot options screen appears:

Advanced options > ***** (recovery mode)
[Accessing recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

This will allow you to access the terminal as root, and update graphics drivers etc.

**AMD graphics**

This may also help your issue with AMD drivers, which might be your problem.

[How to remove proprietary AMD drivers & repair Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/299466/322860)

Comment: Desktop environment I am using is not Unity, it is Gnome.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Do any graphics load? What specifically happens at the login screen?

Comment: Yes, it loads upto login screen. Even after providing "right" password it does not log me in. Anyways, I managed to resolve my problem, GUI is back now.